# Calculation of $\zeta(2)$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

I was attempting to calculate the value of $\zeta(2)$ (I already knew what the value is, but I was trying to derive it). I started with the sum
$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}$$
and I created the function
$$g(a)=\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{a^x}{x^2}$$
and differentiated both sides to get
$$g'(a)=\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{a^{x-1}}{x}$$
$$ag'(a)=\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{a^x}{x}$$
I then used the formula
$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{a^x}{x}=-\ln(|1-a|)$$
and so
$$ag'(a)=-\ln(|1-a|)$$
$$g'(a)=-\frac{\ln(|1-a|)}{a}$$
Since $\zeta(2)=g(1)$, does that mean that
$$\zeta(2)=-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(|1-a|)}{a}$$
Is my reasoning correct here? If so, how do I evaluate this integral? I can't seem to find an indefinite integral for it.

Comment: WA says your integral is indeed $\pi^2/6$, and your reasoning looks right to me. That said, it gives no elementary antiderivative of the function. You could try some kind of contour maybe, but morale is low as to whether this integral can be evaluated with any kind of ease.

Comment: The last integral is a definition of the dilogarithm. ie $$\zeta(2) = Li_{2}(1).$$

Comment: You can use $-\log(1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n }{n}$
To show that 
$g(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi nt)}{\pi n}=t-\lfloor t \rfloor-\frac12$
So that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}= 2\pi^2 \int_0^1 |g(t)|^2 =\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: Have a look at this historical thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: hystorical or histerical ? ;-)

Comment: Your formula is correct (+1). However, since $0\lt a\lt1$, you don't need the absolute values. They don't buy anything here anyway; if $1-a\lt0$, then the series doesn't converge.

Answer (score 5):

Another derivation of this formula would be to use 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{n} =\int_0^1 x^{n-1} dx \\
\frac{1}{n} =\int_0^1 y^{n-1} dy
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\zeta(2)&=& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \\
 &=& \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n-1} y^{n-1} \; dy \; dx \\
  &=& \int_0^1 \int_0^1  \frac{ \; dy \; dx }{1-xy}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now do one of these integrations and your formula follows.

Answer (score 5):

Let's go back to the Taylor expansion of the logarithm:

$$-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$$

By consider $x\mapsto e^{ix}$ under the principal branch, we find that

$$-\operatorname{Log}(1-e^{ix})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{inx}}n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)}n$$

Taking imaginary parts, we find that

$$\begin{align}\Im(-\operatorname{Log}(1-e^{ix}))&=-\arg(1-e^{ix})\\&=-\arg(1-\cos(x)-i\sin(x))\\&=\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\right)\end{align}$$

Where $\arctan(x)\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.  With a few tricky half angle formulas, one further finds that

$$\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\right)=\frac\pi2-\frac x2,\quad x\in(0,2\pi)$$

Likewise, taking the imaginary part of our RHS, we find that,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}n=\frac\pi2-\frac x2$$

Integrate both sides over $x\in[0,\pi]$ we find that

$$\begin{align}\int_0^\pi\frac\pi2-\frac x2~\mathrm dx&=\frac{\pi^2}4\\&=\int_0^\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}n~\mathrm dx\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac2{(2n-1)^2}\\&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{(2n)^2}\\&=\frac32\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\end{align}$$

where we noted that $\int_0^\pi\sin(nx)~\mathrm dx$ equaled zero when $n$ was even and $2/n$ when $n$ was odd.

> $$\therefore\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac23\frac{\pi^2}4=\frac{\pi^2}6$$

Comment: Feel free to integrate a few more times to get $\zeta(2n)$.

Comment: I would remove the 1st part. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{sin(n x)}{n} =\frac{\pi - x}{2}$ on $(0,2\pi)$ follows from $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n x)}{n} =\lim_{r \to 1^-} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Im(r^n e^{in x})}{n}  =  \lim_{r \to 1^-} \Im(-\log(1-r e^{ix}))\\ = \lim_{r \to 1^-} \Im(\log(r e^{i\frac{ \pi-x}{2}}) -\log(\frac{r e^{-ix/2} - r e^{ix/2}}{i}))  = \frac{\pi - x}{2}$$